# Fail to get exact Centos kernel version

Tags: centos, kernel, ebpf

`uname -a`  tells the "kernel version" is  `3.10.0`

```
[root@iZbp16uggk8lf3x949ewxiZ ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
[root@iZbp16uggk8lf3x949ewxiZ ~]# uname -a
Linux iZbp16uggk8lf3x949ewxiZ 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 18 16:35:19 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`LINUX_VERSION_CODE` also says current kernel version is `3.10.0`

```
[root@iZbp16uggk8lf3x949ewxiZ ~]# grep -rni "LINUX_VERSION_CODE" /usr/include/
/usr/include/linux/version.h:1:#define LINUX_VERSION_CODE 199168
```

But When I find a kernel function `tcp_rtx_synack` exist

```
[root@iZbp16uggk8lf3x949ewxiZ ~]# cat /proc/kallsyms | grep tcp_rtx_synack
ffffffff952a0700 t tcp_rtx_synack.part.26
ffffffff952a0730 T tcp_rtx_synack
ffffffff95721f90 r __ksymtab_tcp_rtx_synack
ffffffff95739e78 r __kcrctab_tcp_rtx_synack
ffffffff95765c36 r __kstrtab_tcp_rtx_synack
```

3.17 https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.17/A/ident/tcp_rtx_synack  func `tcp_rtx_synack` exist
3.16 https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.17/A/ident/tcp_rtx_synack  func `tcp_rtx_synack` not exist
Which means my centos kernel version is at least `3.17` not `3.10`

I'm writting the eBPF which need more exact kernel version info because function and data struct are different from each kernel version.

I have buy two VMs on different Cloud provisioner and both VMs show like above.

Answer (score 2):

CentOS, like RHEL, **contains backports of various patches (features, fixes, etc.) to older kernel versions**. So you can't rely on the kernel version to know which features or functions are available.

Instead, you can either probe for the available features from userspace (e.g., with `bpftool feature probe`) or [use CO-RE to detect it with BTF](https://nakryiko.com/posts/bpf-core-reference-guide/#dealing-with-kernel-changes-and-feature-detection).